# Object not lit when using Vuforia AR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I am trying to experiment with ARCore and Unity using Vuforia and I have some trouble with object not being lit up. The whole object is dark and I tried a few different lighting settings too.

Can you help?

Here are some screenshots:

Phone:
[image]

Unity:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

So I tried it with a different object downloaded from the asset store (a tree) and if works flawlessly with that. So the problem must be with the knight... but what is it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a directional light GameObject to the scene (but I guess it works with any light object).

Right Click > Light > Directional Light

Here is my light object configuration:
[Directional Light Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDn5D.jpg)

It works flawlessly. Hope it works for you.
Let me know if this solved the problem.

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't work. I tried placing my light into the camera, the game object, outside of everything... nothing help. The problem seems to be with the material on the knight. I downloaded this knight from the asset store, maybe see if it works for you?

Comment: Just saw your edit. I'm glad you made it work. As for what it could be, I would need more information to provide you with an answer. It probably has something to do with the material you used on the knight. You can try to play with the material's settings. Or compare them with the settings from your tree model.

Answer (score 1):

Check material of the game object. If it’s Standard then change it to Lit Image or transparent or transparent cutout whatever you texture type.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directional light is directed correctly towards the object

Comment: I don't mean that you should add one, i mean make sure the it's not directed away from where your object is

Comment: Oh, yeah, it is pointed towards the object but check out my update to the question in a second

Answer (score 0):

Just realized how old this is, but the answer was to turn up the Lightmap Encoding in the Player Settings when building the app.  File>Build Settings>Player Settings>Player. Mine defaulted to Low, and I switched it to Normal.

You may also need to update the default quality level to at least Medium.